# Which EPEL release do I need?

Tags: linux, epel

I have a 64 bit server machine with:

```
Oracle Linux Server release 6.5
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

and **I need to install EPEL repository**. I've already tried few of them:

```
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/epel-release-t-5.noarch.rpm
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

but after their installation(e.g. `rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`) I'm getting the following message when trying to `yum` e.g.:

```
# yum repolist
Error: xz compression not available
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL and there you can find more information about the EPEL

Comment: @c4f4t0r not of much help. this error persists regardless of which epel release I download and install.

Comment: rpm -qa | grep -i epel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to `rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel` because there was some leftovers from wrong version and

```
rpm -ivh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS the extras repository, which is enabled by default, contains a package to install/enable EPEL called `epel-release`. Likely Oracle Linux has it someplace in the regular repositories as well.

`yum install epel-release`